# Efficient way to perform UPSERT in DynamoDB for multiple items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, upsert

In DynamoDB , we will have 20000 records . Each request has 4 itemId for which the records has to be  updated if exist / inserted if record for that itemId is not available .

updateItem would be the option , but documentation says we cannot update multiple Items in one API call . What would be the right option for this use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use UpdateItem API with an asynchronous client, and if needed use multiple threads to speed up the processing.

You can also use `BatchExecuteStatement` to update multiple items at the same time, but I would suggest not going down that path.

Comment: That would be 4 API calls . Can't we do that in single API call ? Why we shouldn't be using BatchExecuteStatement .

Comment: Because BatchExecuteStatement wasn't created to support batch updating, and would be synchronous on the backend. Yea it would be 4 API calls, but asynchronously which should be just as fast as 1.

Comment: If the 4 requests are dependent on each other, you can use TransactWriteItems

Comment: Each requests are not dependent on each other . Can BatchWriteItem be an option ?

Comment: No, there is no Update for BatchWriteItem

Comment: Documentation says BatchWriteItem  replaces existing record which is kind of update

Comment: Its not an update, its an overwrite. They are not the same.